# how to wrap the width of gridview item dynamically in android

Tags: android, gridview

[image]

I am developing an application in android.i want to set the gridview item dynamically as shown in the below image.someone suggest with a solution .

Comment: some one guide for the above problem with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager instead of GridView. You can find a good tutorial here [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

You can control the size of your item from within the grid adapter - more specifically in your overridden `getView()` method :

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);

    // ...

    AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.
        WRAP_CONTENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.width = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.card_width);
    lp.height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.card_height);
    v.setLayoutParams(lp);

    return v;
}
```